# MySQL two table inner join and count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
// bookmark
| id | user | title |

// bookmarkItem
| itemID | bookmarkId |
```

I try to select from one user's all bookmark and count how many items in there.
I have a half working sql:

```
SELECT
    bookmark.id,
    bookmark.title,
    COUNT(bookmarkItem.itemId) AS count
FROM
    bookmark
    INNER JOIN bookmarkItem ON bookmark.id = bookmarkItem.bookmarkId
WHERE
    bookmark.user = 'username'
GROUP BY
    bookmark.id
```

But it doesn't write the bookmark with zero bookmarkItem-s. What I want is to show that lines to, like:

```
| id | title | count |
|----|-------|-------|
| 12 | asdfg |   15  |
| 13 | asdfh |   0   |
| 14 | asdfj |  145  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you only select bookmarks with matching bookmark items. (This is how an **INNER JOIN** works. You need an **OUTER JOIN** instead.)

Change

```
INNER JOIN
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN
```

so as to also get bookmarks without bookmark items.

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN on bookmark table. This will give all records from bookmark table, even if bookmarkItem does not have any matching record.